# Print: producing no output

Tags: perl, printing

I'm fairly confused. I just got a new development machine, and perl appears to be outputting nothing for **print** commands.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
print "A";
print STDOUT "B";
print STDERR "C";
open FH, ">", "testprint';
print FH "D";
close FH;
```

Produces nothing in the console, and **testprint** becomes a 1-bye (empty) file.

Even this produces nothing:

```
perl -e "print 'a';"
```

This occurs for both perl binaries that happen to be on my machine. I'm stumped about where to start debugging this problem. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

```
perl -v

This is perl, v5.8.8 built for x86_64-linx-thread-multi
```

and

```
which perl

/usr/bin/perl
```

Comment: More info would help. Try: `perl -V`  and `which perl`

Also, add `use warnings;` and `use strict;` to your script

Comment: Added the info you requested.

Comment: What the heck is `perl v5.5.5`? [There has never been any official release with that version number](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlhist) and even if there was, it would be ancient. Upgrade your `perl` installation.

Comment: your perl seems to be confused about your STDOUT.  Do other programs work as expected?  Does this script work:  `#!/bin/sh` `echo foo`

Comment: are you missing a double quote here: `open FH, ">", "testprint'`

Comment: 1) As mentioned by @ikegami below, add newlines. Your prompt might overwrite your output.
2) A one-byte file is exactly what should be produced by a one-byte print into a file, shouldn't it? (Except when using 2-byte encodings.)

Comment: A "a 1-bye (empty) file." is a contradiction by itself. You should have tried "`hexdump -C testfile`" to see that there was actually a `D` in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was not `STDOUT` missing or redirected from the shell, but rather that the shell was set to send a carriage return without a newline when writing a prompt, thus overwriting all output sent to the same line.

Specifically, my old version of `zsh` had `promptcr` set. See [question 3.23 here](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/zshfaq03.html) for more information.

Comment: (I had actually mentioned that.)

Answer (score 10):

I believe the problem exists outside of Perl. Either

- the terminal in some unusual state when you ran the script,
- `perl`'s parent process redirected `perl`'s output away from the terminal, or
- `perl`'s parent process did not provide a STDOUT and STDERR for `perl`.

You might be able to gather more information by actually checking if `print` returned an error. (It always baffles me why people don't check for errors when something doesn't work they way they expect it to work.)

```
perl -we'print("a") or die("Can'\''t print: $!\n");'
```

You might be able to gather more information by using `strace` or whatever it's called on your system. (Look for `write(1` and `write(2`.)

```
strace perl -we'print("a") or die("Can'\''t print: $!\n");'
```

But those should print nothing at all if the problem is outside of Perl, which is why it might be wise to try redirecting the output to a file and then examining the file and its size.

```
perl -we'print("a") or die("Can'\''t print: $!\n");' 1>out 2>err
```

Comment: @JoshJordan, Also, try `\perl` instead of `perl`. Maybe you have an alias?

Comment: @JoshJordan, Also, try `"a\n"` instead of `"a"`. You are perhaps overwriting your output with later output (e.g. your prompt)