# Why does Perl's print fail to output anything to STDOUT and STDERR, but writes to a file successfully?

Tags: bash, perl

I'm attempting to print to standard out from the following Perl script, but it doesn't produce any output on the screen.  It does print to a file, however.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

print "Here's some text\n";
print STDERR "Here's some text\n";
print STDOUT "Here's some text\n";

open FH, ">", "file.txt" or die $!;

print FH "Here's some text\n";
```

I tried checking the version of perl I'm using (`perl -v`), but that doesn't output anything either.  The perl man page tells me I'm using 5.14.2.  I'm running the Perl script from a bash prompt from a Raspberry Pi.

I saw this similar post [Print: producing no output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830610/print-producing-no-output), so I used strace and saw that the output did not include any write commands.

```
strace perl -we'print("a") or die("Can'\''t print: $!\n");'
```

Here's the strace output for the full script:

```
execve("./response", ["./response"], [/* 18 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0xd98000
uname({sys="Linux", node="raspberrypi", ...}) = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap2(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb6f99000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = 0
open("/etc/ld.so.preload", O_RDONLY)    = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=44, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 44, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xb6f98000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcofi_rpi.so", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\270\4\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 7276, SEEK_SET)                = 7276
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1080) = 1080
lseek(3, 7001, SEEK_SET)                = 7001
read(3, "A.\0\0\0aeabi\0\1$\0\0\0\0056\0\6\6\10\1\t\1\n\2\22\4\24\1\25"..., 47) = 47
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=10170, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 39740, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb6f6c000
mprotect(0xb6f6e000, 28672, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0xb6f75000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1) = 0xb6f75000
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0xb6f98000, 44)                  = 0
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=64456, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 64456, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xb6f5c000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/libperl.so.5.14", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\220\v\2\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 1346508, SEEK_SET)             = 1346508
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1120) = 1120
lseek(3, 1346184, SEEK_SET)             = 1346184
read(3, "A2\0\0\0aeabi\0\1(\0\0\0\0056\0\6\6\10\1\t\1\n\2\22\4\24\1\25"..., 51) = 51
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1347628, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 1379192, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb6e0b000
mprotect(0xb6f4f000, 32768, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0xb6f57000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x144) = 0xb6f57000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0(\t\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 8652, SEEK_SET)                = 8652
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1160) = 1160
lseek(3, 8320, SEEK_SET)                = 8320
read(3, "A0\0\0\0aeabi\0\1&\0\0\0\0056\0\6\6\10\1\t\1\n\2\22\4\24\1\25"..., 49) = 49
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=9812, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 41136, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb6e00000
mprotect(0xb6e02000, 28672, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0xb6e09000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1) = 0xb6e09000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\3201\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 426468, SEEK_SET)              = 426468
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1160) = 1160
lseek(3, 426136, SEEK_SET)              = 426136
read(3, "A0\0\0\0aeabi\0\1&\0\0\0\0056\0\6\6\10\1\t\1\n\2\22\4\24\1\25"..., 49) = 49
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=427628, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 458912, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb6d8f000
mprotect(0xb6df7000, 28672, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0xb6dfe000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x67) = 0xb6dfe000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\274V\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 82712, SEEK_SET)               = 82712
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1400) = 1400
lseek(3, 82308, SEEK_SET)               = 82308
read(3, "A0\0\0\0aeabi\0\1&\0\0\0\0056\0\6\6\10\1\t\1\n\2\22\4\24\1\25"..., 49) = 49
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=116462, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 123412, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb6d70000
mprotect(0xb6d84000, 28672, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0xb6d8b000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x13) = 0xb6d8b000
mmap2(0xb6d8d000, 4628, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb6d8d000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\214y\1\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 1215264, SEEK_SET)             = 1215264
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1360) = 1360
lseek(3, 1214828, SEEK_SET)             = 1214828
read(3, "A.\0\0\0aeabi\0\1$\0\0\0\0056\0\6\6\10\1\t\1\n\2\22\4\24\1\25"..., 47) = 47
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1216624, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb6f98000
mmap2(NULL, 1258784, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb6c3c000
mprotect(0xb6d62000, 32768, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0xb6d6a000, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x126) = 0xb6d6a000
mmap2(0xb6d6d000, 9504, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb6d6d000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcrypt.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\30\7\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 29116, SEEK_SET)               = 29116
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1160) = 1160
lseek(3, 28780, SEEK_SET)               = 28780
read(3, "A0\0\0\0aeabi\0\1&\0\0\0\0056\0\6\6\10\1\t\1\n\2\22\4\24\1\25"..., 49) = 49
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=30276, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 221504, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb6c05000
mprotect(0xb6c0c000, 28672, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0xb6c13000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6) = 0xb6c13000
mmap2(0xb6c15000, 155968, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb6c15000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0`\364\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 130212, SEEK_SET)              = 130212
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1160) = 1160
lseek(3, 129880, SEEK_SET)              = 129880
read(3, "A2\0\0\0aeabi\0\1(\0\0\0\0056\0\6\6\10\1\t\1\n\2\22\4\24\1\25"..., 51) = 51
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=131372, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 162704, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb6bdd000
mprotect(0xb6bfd000, 28672, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0xb6c04000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1f) = 0xb6c04000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb6f97000
set_tls(0xb6f976d0, 0xb6f97da8, 0xb6f9c048, 0xb6f976d0, 0xb6f9c048) = 0
mprotect(0xb6c13000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xb6d6a000, 8192, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xb6d8b000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xb6dfe000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xb6e09000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xb6f57000, 8192, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0x11000, 4096, PROT_READ)      = 0
mprotect(0xb6f9b000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
munmap(0xb6f5c000, 64456)               = 0
set_tid_address(0xb6f97278)             = 12607
set_robust_list(0xb6f97280, 0xc)        = 0
futex(0xbece6778, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 1, NULL, b6d8c000) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {0xb6d7520c, [], SA_SIGINFO|0x4000000}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {0xb6d750b4, [], SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO|0x4000000}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM_INFINITY}) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGFPE, {SIG_IGN, [FPE], SA_RESTART|0x4000000}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0xd98000
brk(0xdb9000)                           = 0xdb9000
getuid32()                              = 1001
geteuid32()                             = 1001
getgid32()                              = 1004
getegid32()                             = 1004
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1534656, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 1534656, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xb6a66000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
read(3, "~\210\223\234", 4)             = 4
close(3)                                = 0
gettimeofday({1460938704, 307768}, NULL) = 0
readlink("/proc/self/exe", "/usr/bin/perl", 4095) = 13
stat64("/usr/local/lib/site_perl/5.14.2/arm-linux-gnueabihf-thread-multi-64int", 0xbece6368) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/local/lib/site_perl/5.14.2", 0xbece6368) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/local/lib/site_perl/arm-linux-gnueabihf-thread-multi-64int", 0xbece6368) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("./response", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
ioctl(3, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, 0xbece627c) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
_llseek(3, 0, [0], SEEK_CUR)            = 0
fcntl64(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)         = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
brk(0xddb000)                           = 0xddb000
read(3, "#!/usr/bin/perl\nuse warnings;\nus"..., 8192) = 210
stat64("/etc/perl/warnings.pmc", 0xbece5e10) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/etc/perl/warnings.pm", 0xbece5d90) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2/warnings.pmc", 0xbece5e10) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2/warnings.pm", 0xbece5d90) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/warnings.pmc", 0xbece5e10) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/warnings.pm", 0xbece5d90) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/perl5/warnings.pmc", 0xbece5e10) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/perl5/warnings.pm", 0xbece5d90) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/share/perl5/warnings.pmc", 0xbece5e10) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/share/perl5/warnings.pm", 0xbece5d90) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/perl/5.14/warnings.pmc", 0xbece5e10) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/perl/5.14/warnings.pm", 0xbece5d90) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/share/perl/5.14/warnings.pmc", 0xbece5e10) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/share/perl/5.14/warnings.pm", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=15015, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/share/perl/5.14/warnings.pm", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
ioctl(4, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, 0xbece5be4) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
_llseek(4, 0, [0], SEEK_CUR)            = 0
read(4, "# -*- buffer-read-only: t -*-\n# "..., 8192) = 8192
read(4, "08\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x"..., 8192) = 6823
read(4, "", 8192)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
brk(0xdfc000)                           = 0xdfc000
stat64("/etc/perl/strict.pmc", 0xbece5e10) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/etc/perl/strict.pm", 0xbece5d90) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2/strict.pmc", 0xbece5e10) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2/strict.pm", 0xbece5d90) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/strict.pmc", 0xbece5e10) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/strict.pm", 0xbece5d90) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/perl5/strict.pmc", 0xbece5e10) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/perl5/strict.pm", 0xbece5d90) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/share/perl5/strict.pmc", 0xbece5e10) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/share/perl5/strict.pm", 0xbece5d90) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/perl/5.14/strict.pmc", 0xbece5e10) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/perl/5.14/strict.pm", 0xbece5d90) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/share/perl/5.14/strict.pmc", 0xbece5e10) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/share/perl/5.14/strict.pm", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=879, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/share/perl/5.14/strict.pm", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 4
ioctl(4, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, 0xbece5be4) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
_llseek(4, 0, [0], SEEK_CUR)            = 0
read(4, "package strict;\n\n$strict::VERSIO"..., 8192) = 879
_llseek(4, 878, [878], SEEK_SET)        = 0
_llseek(4, 0, [878], SEEK_CUR)          = 0
close(4)                                = 0
read(3, "", 8192)                       = 0
open("file.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = 4
ioctl(4, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, 0xbece614c) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
_llseek(4, 0, [0], SEEK_CUR)            = 0
fstat64(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
fcntl64(4, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)         = 0
rt_sigaction(SIG_0, NULL, {0xb6e18dc4, [TRAP RTMIN RT_1 RT_2 RT_3 RT_12 RT_13 RT_15 RT_16 RT_18 RT_19 RT_20 RT_25 RT_26 RT_27 RT_28 RT_29], SA_SIGINFO|0x85b8}, 8) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGILL, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTRAP, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGABRT, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGBUS, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGFPE, NULL, {SIG_IGN, [FPE], SA_RESTART|0x4000000}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGKILL, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGUSR1, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGSEGV, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGUSR2, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGSTKFLT, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCONT, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGSTOP, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTIN, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTOU, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGURG, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGXCPU, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGXFSZ, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGVTALRM, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPROF, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGWINCH, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGIO, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPWR, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGSYS, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_2, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_3, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_4, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_5, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_6, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_7, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_8, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_9, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_10, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_11, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_12, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_13, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_14, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_15, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_16, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_17, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_18, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_19, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_20, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_21, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_22, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_23, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_24, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_25, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_26, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_27, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_28, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_29, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_30, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_31, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_32, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGABRT, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGIO, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGSYS, NULL, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
write(4, "Here's some text\n", 17)      = 17
close(4)                                = 0
close(3)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

Any ideas about why it's not producing output?  A bash script can echo text to standard out just fine.

When I run the script in debug mode it does print output.

After executing perl -v at the command line the exit code from $? was 0.

Executing

```
perl -e'print "foo" or die $!'
```

gave and exit code of 9, but that appears to be due to the die.  perl -v > file did not write anything to file.

Here is the output of stat STDOUT and the command used to write it to a file:

45826|261126|33188|1|1001|1004|0|0|1461024408|1461035504|1461035504|4096|0

```
perl -e 'open my $FH, ">file"; print $FH join "|", stat STDOUT '
```

Comment: If `perl -v` doesn't produce any output either, the problem is not likely to be in perl.

Comment: @Henrik: did you mean "if `perl -v` doesn't produce any output either, the problem _is_ likely to be with the installation of Perl"?  That would be my interpretation of 'no output from `perl -v`'; if that doesn't produce a version number and copyright notice (I get the first two lines as `This is perl 5, version 22, subversion 0 (v5.22.0) built for darwin-2level` and `Copyright 1987-2015, Larry Wall`, plus some more licence information), then there is a major problem with Perl.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Or with the terminal, But you're right the problem might be with the installation of perl, but it's unlikely to be withthe perl code - which was actually what I meant.

Comment: I hadn't considered terminal mode, etc, but I suppose it could be that.  I'd certainly want to know what you've done.  I suppose `exec >/dev/null` in the shell could do it; standard error and prompts would appear, but not standard output.  It's a little eccentric to try stuff like that, though.

Comment: @SaintHax I think your edit to remove the bash tag was premature. In a [similar issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9841592/176646) that the OP linked to, the cause was actually a shell setting. There's not enough information at this point to rule out bash as the cause, so the tag should stay.

Comment: By the way, in modern perl you open a file like this: `open my $FH, ">", "file.txt" or die $!;`, i.e. you don't use *bareword* file handles.

Comment: Curious: the `strace` output doesn't contain any attempt to write to other than the `FH` handle (file descriptor 4).  That's extremely puzzling.

Comment: I have no idea about the cause, but there are several things I'd be looking at: is that ld preload library really necessary? If you run `perl -v > file` does it work? What if you do a redirection in the perl code (`open STDOUT, ">file"; print "hello\n"`)? What do you get if you `stat` STDIN, STDOUT, and STDERR in the perl and print the results to a file?

Comment: The perl script you show does not match the strace, as the `read()` of the script file shows the beginning of what's presumably a third `use` statement.  Can we see a full strace of a simpler failure like `perl -v`?  Also, what happens if you skip the library preloading (_ld.so.preload_)?

Comment: @pilcrow Where do you see evidence of a third `use` statement? `read(3, "#!/usr/bin/perl\nuse warnings;\nus"..., 8192) = 210` indicates that the script is 210 bytes long, which is exactly how long the script in the question is. Also, the `strace` output I get on a Debian system matches the OP's very closely, except for the missing `write` calls.

Comment: Ah, yes, @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, my mistake re: additional use.

Comment: What is $PERLIO, your `Config` for your perl's io, and any relevant encodings?  With PERLIO=pop (a known bad/experimental layer) under 5.16 I can get the EBADF exit seen by @ThisSuitIsBlackNot in `print "foo" or die $!` and write() syscalls simply do not happen.  I cannot reproduce your "file write()s ok but STDOUT/STDERR write()s missing" ... but perlio might be a start.

Comment: Please post the output of `ls -l /proc/$$/fd` and `perl -e 'system q(ls -l /proc/$PPID/fd)'` (if this outputs nothing, run `perl -e 'system q(ls -l /proc/$PPID/fd >parent-fd)'` and post the content of `parent-fd`) and, if different, repeat the `system …` thing from your script. Do you get the same behavior if you move your `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc` and `.profile` out of the way before logging in?

Comment: What are your STDOUT and STDERR?

`print fileno( STDOUT ), ' - ', fileno( STDERR );`

What output is for `echo "HELLO"` when you run that in shell?

Answer (score 6):

Before starting reading have a look at the output of this command. Everything is pointing to STDOUT pointing to the incorrect place.

```
ls -l /proc/$$/fd/{1,2}
```

On my system I get this, note it does change as I write this because this was not written in one go.

```
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 May  3 17:01 /proc/27806/fd/1 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 May  3 17:01 /proc/27806/fd/2 -> /dev/pts/1
```

I suspect the above to be similar for you. The stat looks suspicious to me, if I had access to the filesytem I'd search for the inode that it's telling me its writing to ie.

```
sudo find / -printf "%i:\t%p\n"|grep 261126
```

If when Perl starts it's changing it's stdout etc to the wrong place I'd add a very long sleep to the script then do the search to see where it is. If the file is a regular file and it's on the filesystem this should find it.

My stat on STDOUT

```
|dev   |inode  |mode  |link |uid |gid |rdev |size |atime     |mtime     |ctime     |blk |blka
|13    |3      |8592  |1    |1000|5   |34816|0    |1462301986|1462301986|1462301958|1024|0
```

Your stat on STDOUT

```
|dev   |inode  |mode  |link |uid |gid |rdev |size |atime     |mtime     |ctime     |blk |blka
|45826 |261126 |33188 |1    |1001|1004|0    |0    |1461024408|1461035504|1461035504|4096|0
```

On mine my `dev` has minor number 13 and looks ok when I search for it under devices. If we mask yours off to show major/minor you have...

```
major == 179
minor == 2
```

Note, I originally had these in reverse until corrected by [Wumpus Q. Wumbley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2404501/wumpus-q-wumbley).

On my machine this is

```
crw-------  1 root  root   2, 179 Apr 29 12:50 ptya3
```

On mine my `rdev` equates to

```
major == 136 
minor == 0
```

On my Debian system this is `/dev/pts/0`. Your `rdev` is 0. I had a quick look round and some people using screen can have problems with `/dev/pts/N` ie it's not there but that's me guessing.

The strace is also really odd, I got the following lines when it wrote on my system:

```
read(3, "#!/usr/bin/perl -w\n#use strict;\n"..., 8192) = 228
read(3, "", 8192)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
write(1, "Here's some text STDOUT\n", 24Here's some text STDOUT
) = 24
write(2, "Here's some text STDERR\n", 24Here's some text STDERR
) = 24
write(1, "Here's some text STDOUT\n", 24Here's some text STDOUT
) = 24
```

The fact that these appear no where in your strace is very strange indeed. You can change where the appear by messing around with `$|` but they should appear somewhere. [Gilles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/387076/gilles) noticed that the mode is also odd. If you run this script...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Fcntl ':mode';
my $mode = 33188;
my $user_rwx      = ($mode & S_IRWXU) >> 6;
print("user_rwx      = $user_rwx\n");
my $group_read    = ($mode & S_IRGRP) >> 3;
print("group_read    = $group_read\n");
my $other_execute    =  $mode & S_IXOTH;
print("other_execute = $other_execute\n");
printf "Permissions are %04o\n", S_IMODE($mode), "\n";
my $is_setuid     =  $mode & S_ISUID;
print("is_setuid     = $is_setuid\n");
my $is_directory  =  S_ISDIR($mode);
print("dir           = $is_directory\n");
my $is_reg  = S_ISREG($mode);
print("regular       = $is_reg\n");
```

You can see that STDOUT appears to be pointing at a regular file. This would confirm why `rdev` is zero ie if stdout was redirecting to something that was meant to be a device but actually was just a normal file. I've seen odd things like that happen in chrooted environments where devices were not setup properly.

Regardless of buffering being on or off on exit the buffers should have have been flushed ie you would see calls to the write sys call. It's really weird that there are no writes at all in the strace.

Comment: I think you've got major and minor reversed. Block device 179,2 would probably be mmcblk0p2 which makes more sense than 2,179 (some kind of floppy). It would be very interesting to see the result of `find / -inum 261126 -ls` since (going by mode=33188=0100644) seems to be a regular file, not a tty (which also explains rdev=0)

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley On my machine 2,179 is /dev/ptsya3 and 136,0 is /dev/pts/0. Different machines might be showing different numbers. I'm on Debian with a 4.5 kernel.

Comment: OK, you are right about 136,0 being 136*256+0=34186 but then 179,2 is 179*256+2=45826. And there are 2 devices for each major,minor number pair: a character device and a block device. The pty you found is the character device 2,179. The block device 2,179 would be fd7h410 (the 3rd floppy drive on the 2nd floppy controller, with a 410K-formatted 5.25-inch disk!)

Comment: And yes, some device numbers are dynamic, so it's not 100% certain that the device in question is mmcblk0p2. But major 2 is definitely not dynamic. It's way too old. Major 179 was statically assigned to mmc at one point; I'm not sure if it's dynamic now.

Comment: You're right that the `stat` data is suspicious, but your analysis isn't quite right. STDOUT is a regular file — check the mode (0100644 — 0100xxx is a regular file, and 0644 is the permissions). The dev field indicates on which partition the file is. The rdev field is 0 because stdout is a regular file, not a device.

Comment: I don't like to repeat myself, but I am 1000% certain that `ptya3` is irrelevant for 2 reasons (make that 2000% certain). It's a char device, and the `st_dev` field of a stat structure can only be a block device. And you've got the major/minor backwards.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley I'm still looking into it.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley I've updated the answer and corrected my major/minor mix up. I should have realized when you said /dev/mmc... that it's an SD card and that fits in nicely with the raspberry.

Comment: In your `ls` output, 2 is the major device number and 179 is the minor, isn't it? That's the opposite of what the OP showed. According to [this](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/docs/lanana/device-list/devices.txt-3June2001), major number 179 corresponds to "CCube DVXChip-based PCI products".

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot There are always two major minors ie for char and block device ie 2/179 and 179/2. In the OP's case on a raspberry he's almost certainly using an SD card.

Comment: I don't follow...in `crw-------  1 root  root   2, 179`, 2 is the major and 179 is the minor, isn't it? Or am I misunderstanding [this](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Partition/devices.html)?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Yes, and on the raspberry there will be an associated block device which is an SD card with 179, 2. See comments from Wumpus previously. Looking up the same doc you referenced I was able to see that this is an SD card. The raspberry I've got it uses an SD card as the block device.

Comment: My point is that the OP's `stat` output shows major 179, minor 2, while your `ls` output shows the opposite, i.e. I think you ran `ls` on the wrong device. Am I missing something?

Comment: That's what Wumpus also pointed out ie the OP's stat is referencing the block device.

Answer (score 4):

There are several interesting clues in the information you've provided:

`perl -e'print "foo" or die $!'` gave an exit code of 9, which is EBADF, implying that STDOUT is pointing to a bad file descriptor. That could either be some arbitrary number (since the underlying file descriptors are just numbers), or it could be a file descriptor which used to be open but is now closed. (That also implies that it's not, say, redirected to /dev/null -- that would result in no output but wouldn't give an error.)

Your `strace` output shows several `open` and `close` calls, and they all appear to be paired--no evidence of closing STDOUT. Importantly, the `open` calls all return FD 3 (and later, FD 4 in a case in which FD 3 is still in use)--on Unix-like systems, `open` typically returns the lowest unused FD, so this is further evidence that FD 1 (the usual STDOUT) hasn't been closed after your process started.

So the implications is that STDOUT is not connected to FD 1, but is associated with some other FD. Running the following should tell you what FD it is:

```
perl -e 'open my $FH, ">", file.txt"; print $FH fileno(STDOUT)'
```

I'm guessing that this will be some arbitrary number, and the result of some problem specific to your installation on your Raspberry Pi--perhaps some corrupt library. But as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36802110/559523) by [Sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1147230/sebastian), you can run `lsof` to find out what FDs your process has opened (add a `sleep` to your script to keep it running), or look in /proc. But probably STDOUT is referring to something that isn't actually an open FD. It's a little curious that your `strace` output doesn't show even error-ing calls to `write`; that implies that Perl does know that the FD is invalid.

Another interesting experiment to try is running this:

```
perl -e 'system qw(echo hello)'
```

If that produces output, then that means that the subprocess is inheriting a still-open FD 1, which is further evidence that Perl is in a bad state and has STDOUT associated with an unexpected FD.

Yet another thing to try is this:

```
perl -le 'open(STDOUT, ">&1"); print "hello"'
```

That's an attempt to "fix" STDOUT by re-opening it with an FD `dup2()`'d from FD 1 (which I'm inferring is still open, and just not associated with STDOUT). If that produces output, then at least it's a possible workaround, though still not an explanation of the original cause (which I fear will remain inscrutable).

One side note: Although `perl -V` isn't giving you any output, you can get the information by running:

```
perl -MConfig -le 'open my $FH, ">", version.txt"; print Config::myconfig(); print foreach Config::local_patches()'
```

The second part, about locally-applied patches, may give a clue as to whether something non-standard was done to the `perl` you have installed.

Comment: Well, this is unfortunate. Two great answers, but the OP is AWOL and I can't reproduce their issue. This is a really tough decision, but I'm awarding the bounty to this one because of the suggested workaround and the suggestion to check `Config` (since the OP claims that Bash scripts work normally, it seems likely that Perl is misconfigured).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Nevermind I can see you added the bounty.

Comment: @Harry Me. I was hoping the OP would actually respond to all the comments and answers, but they never did, even though the "Last Seen" in their profile indicates that they checked in several times since I posted the bounty.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I spent a fair bit of time on this one so I'm a bit surprised, I did most of the analysis on this 5 days prior to this one and I'm not seeing a lot of additional data in this answer that's not already in mine. This is almost certainly a binary distributed install on a raspberry ie Ubuntu or Debian so the likelihood of a binary being misconfigured ie Perl is slim. The workaround proposed is also a guess.

Comment: @Harry I think both answers are excellent, but they both provide slightly different pieces of a puzzle that I can't solve without access to the OP's machine. I have been agonizing over which one to award the bounty for a while, and I even considered just letting it expire. I also considered offering a second bounty to award the other answer...I'm still considering that.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I think the OP likely solved their issue and had no way to recreate it to verify it. If the OP had surfaced and still had the issue my next step would have been a chat room.

Answer (score 1):

Try making a fresh user account and using that to see if the same issue occurs, i would also try it on a newer Perl because i can't reproduce this on a pi that has 5.22 on it.  This seems very much like you have something unexpected in your shell, a broken module installation or you have a mysterious prompt command that is gobbling output.

The lack of writes to STDOUT and STDERR in your strace suggests they were somehow opened the wrong way before that part of the code ran.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `$|=1` after your `use` lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

$|=1;

print "Here's some text\n";
print STDERR "Here's some text\n";
print STDOUT "Here's some text\n";

open FH, ">", "file.txt" or die $!;

print FH "Here's some text\n";
```

Your strace output also shows that the print-to-file is done at script exit, not while the script is running, because of Perl's output buffering.

If the `$|=1` doesn't help: Try getting the FDs used by your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
system "ls -l /proc/$$/fd";
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
system "lsof -p $$";
```

They should give you a hint where the output should go.

Comment: This has nothing to do with buffering, from what I can tell. `print` reports EBADF and bails out before even attempting any I/O. If it were just a buffering issue, there would still be `write` calls. Looks like `pp_print` bails out in the `if` or `else` [here](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/v5.14.4/pp_hot.c#L738) (link is to 5.14.4 since the 5.14.2 tag isn't on the github mirror).