# Perl print does not output to screen (when using Socket)

Tags: perl

I am learning Perl at basic level, I write a program that use Socket client to do a simple task:

when it receive any message from Server, print it to screen and send an "OK" message to server.

But on screen, seem my code does not print any. Here is the code, i tested on Windows and also on Ubuntu but it seem not able to print.

I found a link [Print: producing no output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830610/print-producing-no-output?noredirect=1&lq=1)  and
[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36667502/why-does-perls-print-fail-to-output-anything-to-stdout-and-stderr-but-writes-t?noredirect=1&lq=1)  but it does not help.

I using

```
 perl -v

This is perl 5, version 30, subversion 0 (v5.30.0) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
(with 50 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)
```

Code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket;

my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET (
PeerAddr => '127.0.0.1',
PeerPort => '8112',
Proto => 'tcp',
);

die "cannot connect to sever $!n" unless $socket;

print  "connected to server";

$socket->autoflush();

$socket->send("OK");

while (1) {
    # receive a response of up to 1024 characters from server
    my $response = "";
    $socket->recv($response, 1024);

    chomp $response;
    
    print STDOUT $response;
    
    $socket->send( "OK");
}
```

Comment: STDOUT is normally line buffered. (Block buffered is not connected to a terminal.) I wouldn't expect to see anything until a LF is sent.buffered

Comment: Also, the concept that a call to `recv` will get an entire response is flawed. That's not how streaming protocols (like tcp) work.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Seem i miss this basic point: I add LF (\n) character to print statment and it works

Answer (score 1):

As comment from @ikegami I appended LF (\n) character to string and it print out normally. So just change to.

```
print  "connected to server\n";
```